# AWS Elastic Search Upgrade 2.3 to 5.5 illegal_argument_exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, aws-elasticsearch

We recently upgraded from aws Elasticsearch service 2.3 to 5.5 and in the 5.5 version the pre-signed urls are not working (working for 2.3).
illegal_argument_exception is raised with the following message:
unrecognized parameters: [X-Amz-Algorithm], [X-Amz-Credential], [X-Amz-Date], [X-Amz-Expires], [X-Amz-Signature], [X-Amz-SignedHeaders].

Comment: I'm running into this issue with AWS elasticsearch 6.4. Did you ever resolve it?